# Viewing a contribution graph for a specific date - Github

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to generate a graph on contributions on a specific day within Github instead of using the cmd.

For example, I would need to find out what my collaborators did on 2nd October 2017. So far I have managed to find solutions that uses

```
git log --after="2017-09-01 00:00" --before="2017-09-02 23:59"
```

However, is it possible to generate a new graph similar to the ones shown in the contributors page?

Comment: https://github.com/[org]/[repo]/graphs/contributors?from=2017-07-06&to=2017-07-06&type=c

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? In github contribution page graphs are responsive. You can select any time range in the graph with mouse to see contributions within that time range.

Comment: @hariprasad I did not realize that with the mouse dragging feature. Thank you it helps!